# Как правильно сделать SearchView с выпадающим списком?

Tags: java, android

Пример:

[image: searchView]

Хочу сделать **searchView** c выпадающим списком. Есть класс **SearchDbAdapter**, написанный по статье с habrahabr

Есть виртуальная FTS-таблица, которая содержит два столбца. Первый столбец `(KEY_INPUT)` — это список возможных запросов пользователей. Второй столбец `(KEY_ANKER)` — список html-файлов с якорями соответствующий этим запросам.

```
public class SearchDbAdapter {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mhdb";
    private static final String FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE = "srcht";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_INPUT = "rqst";
    public static final String KEY_ANKER = "ankr";

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " USING fts3(" + KEY_INPUT + "," + KEY_ANKER + ");";

    private final Context mCtx;

    // Массив с поисковыми запросами (темами и разделами, содержащимися в файлах)
    public static final String search_arr[] = {"data1","data2","data3",data4"};
    // Массив с соответствующими им html-файлами с якорями (файлы хранятся в папке assets проекта)
    public static final String ankers_arr[] = {"file1.html#an1","file2.html#an2","file1.html#an3","file1.html#an4"};

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private static SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            int LNGTH = search_arr.length;
            ContentValues initValues = new ContentValues();
            for(int i=0; i<LNGTH; i++){
                initValues.put(KEY_INPUT, search_arr[i]);
                initValues.put(KEY_ANKER, ankers_arr[i]);
                db.insert(FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE, null, initValues);
                initValues.clear();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public SearchDbAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public SearchDbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mCtx);
        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        if (mDbHelper != null) {
            mDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    //метод, возвращающий курсор с данными
    public static Cursor searchAnker(String inputText) throws SQLException {
        inputText = inputText.toLowerCase();
        String query = "SELECT docid as _id," + KEY_INPUT + "," + KEY_ANKER + " FROM " + FTS_VIRTUAL_TABLE + " WHERE " +  KEY_INPUT + " MATCH '" + inputText + "';";
        Cursor mCursor = mDb.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }
}
```

Работа с SearchView ведется следующим образом:

1. В `SearchView` вводится поисковый запрос «data2». Слушатель SearchView вызывает метод **searchAnker()** класса SearchDbAdapter, который возвращает курсор (mCursor), содержащий запросы похожие на введенный текст и соответствующие этим запросам html-файлы с якорями:

   ```
   data2 request 3 — file1.html#an3
   data2 request 4 — file2.html#an4
   ```
2. Содержащиеся в `mCursor` похожие запросы отображаются в выпадающем списке: `data2 request 3, data2 request 4`.
3. При клике по элементам выпадающего списка осуществляется запуск `activity`, в которую с интентом передаётся соответствующее имя html-файла с якорем из `mCursor: file1.html#an3`

Но я не до конца понимаю, **как сделать этот самый выпадающий список.**

Также столкнулся еще с одной проблемой, `searchAnker` почему-то возвращает пустой курсор, попробовал все варианты, которые есть в столбце `KEY_INPUT`.

В методе `onQueryTextChange` я вызываю `searchAnker(query)`, которому передается введенный текст `query`:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Text submit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

            try {
                cursor = sdb.searchAnker(query);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(cursor.getCount() != 0) {
                // формируем столбцы сопоставления
                String[] from = new String[] { SearchDbAdapter.KEY_INPUT};
                int[] to = new int[] { R.id.search_result_text_view };

                // создааем адаптер и настраиваем список
                cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.result_search_item, cursor, from, to, 0);

                searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(cursorAdapter);

                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Что я делаю не так и как правильно реализовать этот выпадающий список?